# Charging a spherical capacitance

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, charge, capacitance

How could one charge a spherical capacitor with a battery or any other emf source?

Answer (score 0):

Its like charging Van de Graaff generator you can charge something like glass rod and transfer the charge acquired to the spherical object.
I suggest you to have a look at this series...
    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yzFQhsq8SF4&list=PLC2CEECFD938FD494

Answer (score 0):

Spherical capacitors can be of 2 types mainly, either you could have an isolated spherical conductor or you can have 2 coencentric spheres.

In case of two coencentric spheres, just attach your battery to the two spheres, the applied potential difference will charge the capacitance in accordance with $$ Q = CV $$

If you have an isolated conductor, you may attach either the positive or negative terminal to the sphere and again it will charge in accordance with the same formulae.

Keep in mind that these charges would normally be negligibly small and extremely hard to observe!